# Not able to find 'bin' files in IntelliJ IDE Project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I could not able to find bin files in my Intellij project, How can I add them ? Can anyone help me ?

[image]

Comment: check the "Project "Structure" in IDEA, it should have some setting for the "Compiler Output" (or similar, usually not an IDEA user myself)

Comment: I don't use it either but am going to take a wild guess that the 'bin files' are created when you compile the source and none has been compiled yet

Comment: Are you referring to generated files, dependencies, something else?
It is not clear which window is being displayed.

Comment: Hi @phreed,  It has not compiled yet. and I have to refer this bin files to add as a path.